# Azure pipeline to read files in a pull request

Tags: r, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a azure pipeline to lint R scripts in a pull request as one of the steps to allow pull requests to be approved and completed.

I can get the pipeline to run R and library everything I need, but I am struggling to find a way to access the R scripts changed in a pull request via the pipeline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to run the lint ONLY on the files that changed in the PR?

Comment: Yes, only the files that have changed.

Comment: Hi friend,  does the answer below resolved your question?  If yes, you could  accept it as an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find changed files of PR with git commands. Add it to the PR validation build, as an example for PR to the master branch:

```
git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR origin/master --name-only -- . > $(Build.StagingDirectory)/repo_changes.txt
```

Here is the example to copy only changed files with PowerShell ([PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops))

```
$targetfolder = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)" + "/"

function CopyFiles{
    param( [string]$source )

    $target = $targetfolder + $source

    New-Item -Force $target
    copy-item $source $target -Force
}

$changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR origin/master --name-only -- .

if ($changes -is [string]){ CopyFiles $changes }
else
{
    if ($changes -is [array])
    {       
        foreach ($change in $changes){ CopyFiles $change }
    }
}
```

The part of yaml file may be like that:

```
jobs:
- job: get_changed_files
  steps:  
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         $targetfolder = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)" + "/"
         
         function CopyFiles{
             param( [string]$source )
         
             $target = $targetfolder + $source
         
             New-Item -Force $target
             copy-item $source $target -Force
         }
         
         $changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR origin/master --name-only -- .
         
         if ($changes -is [string]){ CopyFiles $changes }
         else
         {
             if ($changes -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($change in $changes){ CopyFiles $change }
             }
         }
   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
      artifactName: MyChangedFiles
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I run the script I'm getting an error saying: ##[error]Invalid file path '/__w/1/s'. A path to a .ps1 file is required. Are you able to help with that?

Comment: thank you for the help so far. I'm not getting an error ##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
are you able to also help with that? Much appreciated

Comment: @Greggary that depends on your build agent. I use Azure DevOps hosted agent `vmImage: 'windows-2019'`. It contains PowerShell and pwsh (like any other images https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software). If you want to use `pwsh`, you have to install it to your build agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7.1.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Could I ask one last question? How do I access the changed files? I've put the files in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` using the `targetPath` argument, but when I then try to reference the location using R the filepath is not valid.

Comment: @Greggary I don't use R.If it supports environment variables, you can get the path through `BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY` variable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

Comment: What would the correct syntax be? I'm trying to run bash: `echo $[ dependencies.get_changed_files.outputs['BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY'] ]  ` and I'm getting `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".get_changed_files.outputs['BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY'] ") `

Comment: @Greggary you can find the shell example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cshell#set-variables-in-scripts. The variable may have the following name: `$BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY`